# Copy Mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have Mysql database and want in each 1 hour copy from file X to table Y

I create code but not work 
it's not move

can I select 3 or 4 columns to copy it and withdraw others

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "3600";
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600">
        </head>
        <body dir="rtl">
        <?php
        echo "Update in: ".date("h:i:sa");
            echo"<br>";
    $mysql_hostname = "localhost"; 
    $mysql_user = "test";
    $mysql_password = "test";
    $mysql_database = "test";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$mysql_database};host={$mysql_hostname}", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
            if (!$dbh) { 
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
            } 
            else
            {
            $table_name="x"; 
            $backup_table_name="y";
         $query="INSERT INTO `".$backup_table_name."` SELECT * FROM ".$table_name;
             $dbh->query($query);
             $dbh->query("TRUNCATE `".$table_name."`");
         echo "StartUpdate....................<br>";
            }
        ?>
```

the table x is

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
  `Rates_Rate_Symbol` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_Bid` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_Ask` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_High` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_Low` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_Direction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rates_Rate_Last` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table y I want it as back up table

```
CREATE TABLE `y` (
  `Symbol` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bid` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ask` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `High` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Low` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Direction` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Last` varchar(8) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `backup_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `IDBC` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDBC`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please look at `Insert Into.. Select` statement detail in MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53138873/edit) your question to add details about your original table, and backup table. Please specify which column(s) you want to backup.